# Read multiple columns from single table based on our input string

Tags: sql, hiveql, apache-spark-sql

I want to select multiple columns from single table based on my given input string in sql select statement.

Example :

If input="table_medical"  i want to select the columns like medi_col1,medi_col2,medi_col2
If input="table_pharmacy"  i want to select the columns like medi_phar1,medi_phar2,medi_phar1

sql("select 
case when $input="table_medical" then medi_col1) //like this

please help me to complete this.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @input="table_medical";

SELECT
    CASE WHEN @input="table_medical" THEN medi_col1 ELSE medi_phar1 END  as medi_col1,
    CASE WHEN @input="table_medical" THEN medi_col2 ELSE medi_phar2 END  as medi_col2
    CASE WHEN @input="table_medical" THEN medi_col3 ELSE medi_phar3 END  as col3
FROM MyTable
```

- Data types for `medi_col1` and `medi_phar1` needs to be same (and for the rest of columns too)

Comment: Thanks for your answer let me check and come back to you

Comment: i need to select multiple columns like if @input="table_medical" then medi_col1 as col1,medi_col2 as col2, medi_col3 as cols etc...  how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want this in a single query, then the same number of columns is needed -- and have compatible types.

One method uses `union all`:

```
select medi_col1, medi_col2, medi_col2
from t
where @input = 'table_medical'
union all
select medi_phar1, medi_phar2, medi_phar1
from t
where @input = 'table_pharmacy';
```